# Heroku log warning "(node) sys is deprecated. Use util instead" when script runs

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I have deployed a node script in heroku to be run by a scheduler. But when the script runs I see a warning in the logs.

```
Dec 07 11:01:10 xxx heroku/scheduler.3255 Starting process with command `node bin/script` 
Dec 07 11:01:13 xxx app/scheduler.3255:  (node) sys is deprecated. Use util instead.
```

I have not declared a `engine` section in my `package.json`.

Is a problem with the node version? How can I avoid this warning?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening because (obviously) 'sys' has been deprecated and replaced by 'util'.

If you are not using 'sys' directly (search your codebase for something like `require('sys')` ) then one of the modules that you depend on (or its dependencies) might be.

To find the offending module do an `npm install` on your project and then grep for `require('sys')` (or with double quotes) to see if you can find the module. Example grep command:

```
grep -r "require('sys')" .
```

If you really want that warning to go away and it's in a dependency or sub-dependency then you have a couple of choices:

1. Replace the module that's using `sys` with one that isn't yet provides the same functionality. (Check that there isn't a more recent version of the module that's addressed this issue.)
2. Submit a Pull Request fixing the issue in the module.